# Two commands for the same line not drawn identically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a line with equation `y = (3/5)x + 1` drawn, and I have grid lines drawn using `TikZ`.  Each unit corresponds to `0.5cm`.  The commands

`\draw[<->] ({-7/2},{((3/5)*(-7) + 1)/2}) -- ({7/2},{((3/5)*7 + 1)/2});`

and

`\draw[<->] (-3.5, -3.2)` and `(3.5, 5.2);`

should draw the same lines.  They do not.  At first, I noticed that the points `(-5,-2)`, `(0,1)`, and `(5,4)` did not belong to both lines.  Now, I see that the domains of the two lines are not even the same!

I understand that the first code for the line seems unnecessarily messy.  The `calc` package should be able to "handle" this, though.  There may be occasions when I need to graph a line with a slope of $1/\sqrt{2}$, too.

```
    \documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}


    %Some distances from the origin along the axes are labeled. (The horizontal spacing occupied by
    %the minus sign indicating the additive inverse of a number is ignored so that the number is
    %centered a horizontal or vertical line.)
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (-3,0){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$6$};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (-2,0){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$4$};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (-1,0){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$2$};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (1,0){2};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (2,0){4};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (3,0){6};

    \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (0,-2){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$4$};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (0,-1){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$2$};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (0,1){2};
    \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (0,2){4};


    %The axes are drawn.
    \draw[latex-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[latex-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
    \node [anchor=north west] at (4,0) {$x$};
    \node [anchor=south west] at (0,3) {$y$};


    %A grid on the Cartesian plane is drawn with dashed, gray lines.
    \foreach \x in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5} \draw[dashed,gray!50] (-3.75,\x) -- (3.75,\x);
    \foreach \x in {-3.5,-3,...,3.5} \draw[dashed,gray!50] (\x,-2.75) -- (\x,2.75);

%Line k is drawn with two commands. An equation for the line is y = (3/5)x + 1.
%This line is drawn a bit to the left of the vertical line x=-7
%and a bit  to the right of the vertical line x=7.

%
    \draw[<->] ($({-7/2},{((3/5)*(-7) + 1)/2}) +({(-1/2)/2}, {{(3/5)*((-1/2)/2)}})$)
    -- ($({7/2},{((3/5)*7 + 1)/2}) +({(1/2)/2}, {{(3/5)*((-1/2)/2)}})$);
    %
    \draw[<->] (-3.5,-1.6) -- (3.5,2.6);


    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw[<->,blue,domain=-3.5:3.5] plot (\x,{\x*3/5 + 0.5});`? Check your algebra though. Of course the domain is not the same when the x-coordinates of the endpoints are +/- 15/4, which is not the same as 3.5.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I am looking at your response now.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I saw that you were still on the web site.  (I will delete this message.  I don't know how to "instant message" like you did.)  I had an extra "`/2`" in my original post.  I will edit the post to remove that.  I compiled the code again and the line still does not have `(-5,-2)` and `(5,4)`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I spied my mistake.  I should have `+(0.25,0.15)` and  `+(-0.25,-0.15)`.  I had `0.3` instead of `0.15`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I am really frustrated.  I wasted about an hour and a half on this mistake.  I am sorry to waste your time as well.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I think that this post should be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you overcomplicating, or am I oversimplifying? I'm too stupid to see where you got those coordinate calculations from, don't you just want `\draw[<->] (-7/2,{((3/5)*(-7) + 1)/2}) -- (7/2,{((3/5)*7 + 1)/2});`?

(Incidentally, if you use `pgfplots` you don't have to think about these things at all.)

---

However, your mistake is in the last y-coordinate of the line:

```
\draw[<->] ($({-7/2},{((3/5)*(-7) + 1)/2}) +({(-1/2)/2}, {{(3/5)*((-1/2)/2)}})$)
    -- ($({7/2},{((3/5)*7 + 1)/2}) +({(1/2)/2}, {{(3/5)*((-1/2)/2)}})$);
```

You have (-1/2) where it should be (1/2).

That said, you are really making this harder than you need to. What the `\draw` command above does is to draw the line from -7.5 to 7.5 instead of from -7 to 7. You get exactly the same result by saying

```
\draw[<->] (-7.5/2,{((3/5)*(-7.5) + 1)/2}) -- (7.5/2,{((3/5)*7.5 + 1)/2});
```

which is shorter and easier to read, I think.

Also worth to mention that if your goal was simply to extend the line a bit, you could use `shorten`, as in `\draw[<->,shorten >=-0.125cm,shorten <=-0.125cm] (-7/2,{((3/5)*(-7) + 1)/2}) -- (7/2,{((3/5)*7 + 1)/2});`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Some distances from the origin along the axes are labeled. (The horizontal spacing occupied by
%the minus sign indicating the additive inverse of a number is ignored so that the number is
%centered a horizontal or vertical line.)
\foreach \x in {2,4,6}
  {
   \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (-\x/2,0){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$\x$};
   \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (\x/2,0){$\x$};   
  }

\foreach \y in {2,4,6}
  {
   \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (0,-\y/2,0){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$\y$};
   \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15cm, font=\tiny] at (0,\y/2){$\y$};   
  }


%The axes are drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\node [anchor=north west] at (4,0) {$x$};
\node [anchor=south west] at (0,3) {$y$};


%A grid on the Cartesian plane is drawn with dashed, gray lines.
\foreach \x in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5} \draw[dashed,gray!50] (-3.75,\x) -- (3.75,\x);
\foreach \x in {-3.5,-3,...,3.5} \draw[dashed,gray!50] (\x,-2.75) -- (\x,2.75);



%Line k is drawn with two commands. An equation for the line is y = (3/5)x + 1.
%
\draw[<->,green,ultra thick] (-7.5/2,{((3/5)*(-7.5) + 1)/2}) -- (7.5/2,{((3/5)*7.5 + 1)/2});
%
\draw[<->,red,thick] (-3.5,-1.6) -- (3.5,2.6);

\draw[<->,blue,thin,,samples at={-3.5,3.5}] plot (\x,{\x*3/5 + 0.5});

\draw[<->] ($({-7/2},{((3/5)*(-7) + 1)/2}) +({(-1/2)/2}, {{(3/5)*((-1/2)/2)}})$)
    -- ($({7/2},{((3/5)*7 + 1)/2}) +({(1/2)/2}, {{(3/5)*((1/2)/2)}})$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooop!  I thought that I removed the `+({(-1/2)/2}, {((3/5)*((-1/2)/2))/2})` part of the code that locates the left arrowhead just a bit to the left  of `x=-7` and the `+({(1/2)/2}, {((3/5)*((1/2)/2))/2})` that locates the right arrowhead just a bit to the right of `x=7`.  The explains why the "domains" of the two lines are different.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the grid lines for `x=7` and `x=-7` from interfering with the arrowheads of the line.

Comment: Now that you know why I had this extra code for drawing the line, why aren't the two codes drawing the same line, except for the "domains"?

Comment: @Adelyn So change the x coordinate?

Comment: @Adelyn I haven't checked your algebra, but obviously there is a mistake somewhere. Anyway, have to go, can look at it later.

Comment: I could easily change the `x`-coordinate in this case because the coordinates are finite decimals.  For other occasions, I will want to use the `calc` package and "things" like `+({(-1/2)/2}, {((3/5)*((-1/2)/2))/2})`.  Why not start using the `calc` package on this code?

Comment: @Adelyn (Still here, had to postpone what I was supposed to do.) I don't understand what you mean by finite decimals. Not sure I understood what you meant by interfere either, for that matter.

Comment: The web site says that you sent this comment 40 seconds ago but I saw it two minutes ago.

Comment: In this case, I want the arrowhead to be a bit, which I decided would be 1/8 of a centimeter, to the left of `x=-7`.  Since the slope of the line is 3/5 and the `y`-intercept is `1`, the coordinates of the tip of the left arrowhead are numbers that can be expressed to the thousandths place.

Comment: What I mean by "interfere" here is that I don't want the gray lines to be drawn over the arrowhead.

Comment: @Adelyn About the comment: I accidentally posted an unfinished comment, deleted it and then rewrote it.

Comment: OK.  I saw what you wrote about the comment.  By the way, I just edited my post.  I think the code is correct now.  The plot still does not have `(-5,-2)` and `(5,4)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39688/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-adelyn).